# Symfony 4 API test on test environment

Tags: php, api, symfony, phpunit

I am writing a test for an api `$client->request('POST', 'http://symfony.localhost/purchase', ['headers' => $headers]);`. I set the test environment with a test sqlite db but the API called in the request continues to write on dev db. I suppose the http request do not allow to recognize the environment. 
(P.S. test env works fine, tried with other unit tests). How can I tell to /purchase to use test env?

This is my test:

```
public function testAdd()
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $token = $this->encrypt('testaauser@mail.com', 'carouge', 'basic');
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'Accept'        => 'application/json',
    ];

    $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://symfony.localhost/purchase', ['headers' => $headers]);
    $this->assertEquals(201, $res->getStatusCode());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have said, your http://symfony.localhost is pointing to your DEV environment so when you do the API call you are really doing the call on that environment.

To do what you want, you need to "build" a test environment:

1. Create a new virtualhost within your webserver with a new URL pointing to the same installation of your dev environment but with a new URL (eg: http://symfony.test).
2. [Configure the environment variables for that new virtualhost as stated in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/configuration/external_parameters.html#configuring-environment-variables-in-production). Concretely, you want to set the APP_ENV to test. For example in Apache you write on your virtualhost config:

   SetEnv APP_ENV test
3. Make your API calls to the URL defined on that VirtualHost.

With that your API calls are being done to your test environment.

More information on environments:

https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/configuration/environments.html